# Clean the placeholder text after multiple jumps

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions

I am studying the book "Hacking Vim" by Packt publishing.

In chapter 4 the author gives us an example of a template for HTML files. I followed the guide of the author.

Created a file `~/.vim/templates/html.tpl`:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title><+TITLE+></title>
        <meta name="generator" content="<+GENERATOR+>" />
        <meta name="author" content="<+AUTHOR+>" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <+CONTENT+>
    </body>
</html>
```

Wrote in `~/.vimrc`:

```
" read template content when a new file is created
autocmd BufNewFile * silent! 0r $VIMHOME/templates/%:e.tpl

" Jump to the next placeholder when `Ctrl-j` is placed.
nnoremap <c-j> /<+.\{-1,}+><cr>c/+>/e<cr>
inoremap <c-j> <ESC>/<+.\{-1,}+><cr>c/+/e<cr>
```

Unfortunately, only the first placeholder (`<+TITLE+>`) is cleared when I press <kbd>Ctrl j</kbd>.

After I press <kbd>Ctrl j</kbd> multiple times I get this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
        <meta name="generator" content="GENERATOR+>" />
        <meta name="author" content="AUTHOR+>" />
    </head>
    <body>
        CONTENT+>
    </body>
</html>
```

What should I do to clean the placeholders when jumping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small misspelling in the code.

Here is the corrected version:

```
" read template content when a new file is created
autocmd BufNewFile * silent! 0r $VIMHOME/templates/%:e.tpl

" Jump to the next placeholder when `Ctrl-j` is placed.
nnoremap <c-j> /<+.\{-1,}+><cr>c/+>/e<cr>
inoremap <c-j> <ESC>/<+.\{-1,}+><cr>c/+>/e<cr>
```

You miss a `>` is the `inoremap` `c` operation.

You need to change till the end of `+>` so it is `c/+>/e` and not `c/+/e`.

Comment: Yes, it was in the book: I just missed it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) Welcome to Vim!